# How to integrate an object detection model made in tensorflow with android app?

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

I am currently retraining one of tensorflow’s neural net models for object detection. I was wondering how to actually use this model within the Android app so that I can get live frames or images from the camera that can be processed by the model. How do I go about achieving this? I have thought about using the CameraPreview to get live frames and then process it, but I am not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent sample example by Tensorflow community.

[Please check here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android)

It has both Image Classification and Realtime Object Detection (with SSD) Examples.

Now coming to your question of which/what&How to use an android view, 
you can [check this file from the example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/CameraActivity.java)